# React.js: How to add data property to virtual DOM so it be inherit in rendered DOM?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking to bind a data obj to the property of the rendered DOM element. Similar to what D3, and Jquery does with data().

Is there a way to do that with React.js?

Comment: Can you expand on your use case, what you are going to do with that ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can use `data-xxx` attributes and bind them when rendering react.js elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data-* notation, e.g.:

```
render: function () {
   return React.DOM.div({'data-my-key': 'myValue'}, 'My Div!');
}
```

Note that you must use the spinal-case/kebab-case key notation (`data-myKey` won't work). More specifically, no upper-case letters.

Source: [Tags and Attributes | React](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#supported-attributes)